# Calculate Vertex Position from supplied Position, Rotation, and Scale?

Tags: c#, math, vertex

I have a class called `Cube` in which I render a basic cube to the screen. I've got it working as far as rendering a basic cube of any scale at origin `0, 0, 0`. However, if I want to move the cube, scale any of its axes, or rotate the cube; I have no idea where to begin since I have to achieve this within a `Vertex` object.

```
struct Vertex {
    Vector3 Position;
    Vector3 Normal;
    Vector2 TextureUV;
    Color Color;
}
```

To render a cube of size `1000000` I simply fill the `Position` properties with that value (with regards to negative and positive values to generate the faces).

```
new Vertex(new Vector3(-1000000, -1000000, -1000000), new Vector3(-1, -1, -1), Color.White);
```

`Cube` has four properties:

- Position (`Vector3`).
- Scale (`Vector3`).
- Rotation (`Vector3`).
- Color (`SharpDX.Color`).

My question is, as I am specifying `Vertex` locations, how can I calculate the new position when rotation and position are applied?

I attempted basic subtraction and addition which simply scales the cube differently and the origin remains at `0, 0, 0` (please don't mind the shorthand).

```
new Vertex(new Vector3(P.X - S.X, P.Y - S.Y, P.Z - S.Z), new Vector3(1, 1, 1), Color.White);
```

The above isn't the exact code as it is on a different computer currently.

If you need additional details, please let me know and I will clarify.

---

### The Question

How can I set the position of the vertices based on the supplied position, scale, and rotation vectors?

---

### Test Case

The following test cases are for position only and are to show you how I will test the answers given.

```
// Renders at origin.
Cube myCube = new Cube(new Vector3(0, 0, 0), new Vector3(100, 100, 100), Color.White);
// Renders to the left.
Cube myCubeLeft = new Cube(new Vector3(-250, 0, 0), new Vector3(100, 100, 100), Color.White);
// Renders to the right.
Cube myCubeRight = new Cube(new Vector3(250, 0, 0), new Vector3(100, 100, 100), Color.White);
// Renders above.
Cube myCubeUp = new Cube(new Vector3(0, -250, 0), new Vector3(100, 100, 100), Color.White);
// Renders below.
Cube myCubeDown = new Cube(new Vector3(0, 250, 0), new Vector3(100, 100, 100), Color.White);
```

I will add rotation and scaling test cases later if needed.

Comment: which axis is the rotation?  You can rotate around the X  axis, Y axis, and Z axis.  When rotating around the z-axis the z value remains the same and the X & y points will rotate the same as 2-D square.

Comment: @jdweng The rotation can occur on any or all of the axes.

Comment: What is no rotation?  You are defining a cube by the two opposite corners of the cube, but not specifying the zero degree rotation.  If you hold a cube by the opposite corners you can rotate it 360 degrees.  So what are you calling zero degrees?  Suppose your two vectors were (50,50,50) and (100,100,100).  Or even (50, 100, 150)  and (75, 125, 175)

Comment: @jdweng I believe it should assume values of `1, 1, 1` would be a scale of `1` from the origin point of `0, 0, 0` and no rotation. However something like `1, 2, 1` could mean some form of rotation has been applied. This definitely seems like a complex issue.

Comment: It is complex. A cube is usually defined having right angles.  The simplest solution is to say zero rotation has Z-Axis of cube always parallel to actual Z Axis.  Then the Bottom face of the cube corners can be solved as a 2-D problem.  You know two corners from the input and then have to solve the other 2 corners.  The Top face four corners are then just a Z Offset from bottom corners.  You then only have one type of rotation around the center line between the two initial points.  Any other movement can be achieved by just moving the two given points.